# Euler's Theorem Congruency

Tags: functions

$a^{11762}\equiv   a^2\pmod {25725}$
; the smallest a where in this congruence is false?

Question From Brilliant.org, and I am having trouble understanding the top voted solution (I dont think anyone would answer if i commented on a 3 year old question)

User Otto Bretscher said that:

"If 7 divides $a$ with multiplicity 1 then $a^{11762}\equiv 0 \ne   a^2\pmod{343}$"

Can someone elaborate on this please, why did it say congruent to 0 but not to $a^2$?

Comment: If $7|a$ then $343=7^3|a^3|a^{11762}$ , but $343$ does not divide $a^2$ , if $a$ is divisible by $7$ , but not by $49$ , hence $a=7$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Study the carmichael-function giving a useful extenstion to Euler's theorem.